# Embedding 3D PRC model in LaTeX with custom views visibilities (movie15)

Tags: pdf, 3d, movie15

I'm using the movie15 package to include 3D graphics in my LaTeX document. I have model in PRC file format (generated by Asymptote). You can find all files of interest + my pdf output here: http://www.2shared.com/file/mAWb_VP_/surfaces.html .

I'm getting the pdf output, views are changing the camera position correctly, but... visibility settings of certain parts seems to be ignored. The "Show Blue" view should hide yellow and green plane, but it doesn't. No difference if I use parts names from the model tree in Adobe Reader, or those generated by 3Dgetview option from movie15 package. Neither of those work for me. Does anyone have any clue what is wrong?

Here is the testing **surface.tex** file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\includemovie[
poster,
3Dlights=Headlamp,
label=surfaces,
toolbar=true,
3Daac=30.276689431853366585,
3Dc2c=0 0 1,
3Dcoo=0 0 -1040.755370793648580729,
3Droll=0,
3Droo=1040.755370793648580729,
3Dbg=1 1 1,
3Dviews2=views.vws,
]{388.45125pt}{248.93pt}{surfaces.prc}

\movieref[3Dgetview]{surfaces}{View parameters!}

\end{document}
```

and the views file **views.vws**:

```
VIEW={Show All}
  COO=0 0 -1040.75537109375
  C2C=0 0 1
  ROO=1040.75537109375
  AAC=30.276688383008686
  BGCOLOR=1. 1. 1.
  LIGHTS=Headlamp
  RENDERMODE=Solid
END

VIEW={Show Blue}
  COO=-187.2486572265625 -24.813243865966797 -976.3198852539062
  C2C=0.33296605944633484 -0.0709739476442337 0.9402639269828796
  ROO=1180.2327931698283
  ROLL=66.06585852059459
  AAC=30.276688383008686
  BGCOLOR=1. 1. 1.
  LIGHTS=Headlamp
  RENDERMODE=Solid
  PART={surface_yellow.a0d4eb333793f1bba7202ad56b4ba57a10a0a0d4eb333793f1bba7202ad56b4ba54da02840}
    VISIBLE=false
  END
  PART={surface_green.a0d4eb333793f1bba7202ad56b4ba57a10d0a0d4eb333793f1bba7202ad56b4ba54da02840}
    VISIBLE=false
  END
END
```

Like I said above, I also tried names like surface_yellow or a0d4eb3337..., neither of it worked. I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate with TeXLive 2010, Adobe Reader 9.4.6. I'll be glad for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug, indeed.
Replace line 685 in movie15.sty

```
\pdfstringdef\@MXV@partname{#1}% name of the part
```

with

```
\gdef\@MXV@partname{\pdfescapestring{#1}}% name of the part
```